# Rails file_store cache clears when redploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, deployment, passenger, capistrano

I am constantly developing my rails app and deploying about once every 1 or 2 weeks. I have a lot of content that I would like to be cached for quite awhile. I switched to using rails file_store for caching since the other caching options store the cache in memory which goes away when I have to restart passenger. The problem I am having is that every time I deploy an update, I loose my cache anyway even though it is file based. Is there a way to prevent the cache from clearing when you deploy an update for a rails app? I am using capistrano for deployment and git for version control.

Comment: it's safe to clean cache each time an app is deployed: what if you have a cached page which is an old version of your app?

Comment: If I need to expire a set of cached pages then I will use rails console to expire them manually. This way pages that are not affected by the update are still cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a directory under the shared directory to hold the cache.  In your deploy.rb, make a symlink to the new directory where the old cache directory used to be.  For example, here is a simplified version of how I symlink the log directory:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Re-link log files"
  task :link_logs, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -nfs '#{shared_path}/log' '#{current_path}/log'"
  end
end

# Activate post-deploy re-linking
after 'deploy:symlink', 'deploy:link_logs'
```

Now, whenever I deploy, my logs are continuous across deploys and stored in:
*/path/to/deploy_dir/shared/log*

Comment: This sounds like what I need. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to make a directory in the shared directory. I guess this makes me sound like a total newb. If I make a directory on the server in shared and try this I get this error.ln: creating symbolic link `{#current_path}/cache': No such file or directory

Comment: The # for current_path should be to the left of the opening bracket like: #{current_path}/log

Comment: Thanks JDutil, I edited the typo. Glad it worked for you climber247.